# Integer value not being saved to Preference XML not displaying the value

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm currently developing a calorie app for my class project.  I am having issues saving the value from the profile function calculateTDEE to the shared preference xml. The page i'm currently working on gets information from the user and depending what the user selects determines their calories. That value is then saved in shared preference where it is displayed in the main activity.

I'm still learning android studio and this is my first app I'm developing.

Thank you in advance.

profile java file

```
`public class Profile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

  //adaptors spinners

  ArrayAdapter<String> HeightFeetAdapter;
  ArrayAdapter<String> WeightLBSAdapter;


   //references UI elements
   Button SaveButton;

   Spinner weightSpinner;
   Spinner heightSpinner;
   Spinner goal;
   Spinner gender;
   Spinner activityLevel;

   EditText age;
   private Animation anim;

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,
       false);

       String username = 
       getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");

      TextView userMain = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.User);
      userMain.setText(username);

      age =(EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
      age.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

      heightSpinner = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.HeightSpin);

      weightSpinner = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.WeightSpin);

      activityLevel = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.activity_level);
       ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_activity =   
      ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.activity_level, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
          adapter_activity.setDropDownViewResource
        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdow
    n_item);
    activityLevel.setAdapter(adapter_activity);

     goal = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.goal);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_goal = 
     ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.goal, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      adapter_goal.setDropDownViewResource
      (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      goal.setAdapter(adapter_goal);

     gender = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
      ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_gender = 
     ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

      adapter_gender.setDropDownViewResource
     (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
    gender.setAdapter(adapter_gender);


    SaveButton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    SaveButton.setOnClickListener(this);


    initializeSpinnerAdapters();
    loadLBVal();
    loadFTVal();

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    heightSpinner.startAnimation(anim);

    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    weightSpinner.startAnimation(anim);


    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    SaveButton.startAnimation(anim);

    SharedPreferences userInfo = 
   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), 
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);



    return myView;
}






    public void loadLBVal() {
    weightSpinner.setAdapter(WeightLBSAdapter);
    // set the default lib value
    weightSpinner.setSelection(WeightLBSAdapter.getPosition("170"));
   }


// load the feets value range to the height spinner
public void loadFTVal() {
    heightSpinner.setAdapter(HeightFeetAdapter);
    // set the default value to feets
    heightSpinner.setSelection(HeightFeetAdapter.getPosition("5\"05'"));
  }


   public void initializeSpinnerAdapters() {

    String[] weightLibs = new String[300];
    // loading spinner values for weight
    int k = 299;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
        weightLibs[k--] = String.format("%3d", i);
    }
    // initialize the weightLibsAdapter with the weightLibs values
    WeightLBSAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), 
    R.layout.activity_spinner_item, weightLibs);

    WeightLBSAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    String[] heightFeets = new String[60];
    // loading values  3"0' to 7"11' to the height in feet/inch
    k = 59;
    for (int i = 3; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
            heightFeets[k--] = i + "\"" + String.format("%02d", j) + "'";
        }
    }
    // initialize the heightFeetAdapter with the heightFeets values

    HeightFeetAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),  

     R.layout.activity_spinner_item, heightFeets);

    HeightFeetAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
     (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


  }



    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.savebutton:


            int   activityLevel, goal, gender, age;
            // Get preferences
            float height = getSelectedHeight();
            float weight =  getSelectedWeight();


            activityLevel = 
     ((Spinner)getActivity().findViewById
     (R.id.activity_level)).getSelectedItemPosition();


            goal = ((Spinner)getActivity().
      findViewById(R.id.goal)).getSelectedItemPosition();

           gender= ((Spinner)getActivity().
      findViewById(R.id.gender)).getSelectedItemPosition();


            age = Integer.parseInt(((EditText).
           getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3)));




            int tdee = calculateTDEE(height,weight,activityLevel,age,gender, 
            goal);

            // Save preferences in XML
            SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 
            0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
            editor.putInt("tdee", tdee);
            editor.commit();


            break;
    }
  }


public float getSelectedWeight() {
    String selectedWeightValue = (String)weightSpinner.getSelectedItem();

    return (float) (Float.parseFloat(selectedWeightValue) * 0.45359237);


}



public float getSelectedHeight() {
    String selectedHeightValue = (String)heightSpinner.getSelectedItem();

    // the position is feets and inches, so convert to meters and return
    String feets = selectedHeightValue.substring(0, 1);
    String inches = selectedHeightValue.substring(2, 4);
    return (float) (Float.parseFloat(feets) * 0.3048) +
            (float) (Float.parseFloat(inches) * 0.0254);

}



  public int calculateTDEE(float height, float weight, int activityLevel,
  int 
 age, int gender, int goal) {

    double bmr = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5;
    if(gender == 1) {
        bmr = (10* weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5*age) - 161;
    }
    double activity = 1.25;
    switch(activityLevel) {
        case 1:
            activity = 1.375;
            break;
        case 2:
            activity = 1.55;
            break;
        case 3:
            activity = 1.725;
            break;
        case 4:
            activity = 1.9;
            break;
    }
    double tdee = bmr * activity;
    switch(goal) {
        case 0:
            tdee -=500;
            break;
        case 2:
            tdee +=500;
            break;
    }
    tdee += .5;
    return (int) tdee;
  }
















   @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  }


    @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

   }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
      super.onDetach();
  }

}
```

`

fragment_profile xml

`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="@drawable/imgbackground2"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:id="@+id/User"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_main_title" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="294dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:text="Please Complete Information"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
   <TableLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Age"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
         android:layout_column="1" />
 </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"></RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/gender"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:popupBackground="@color/colorBackground" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="329dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/weightLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="-2dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/WeightSpin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:prompt="@string/weightLabel"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:popupBackground="@drawable/graybackground2"

                android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        </TableRow>



        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="@string/heightLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/HeightSpin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:prompt="@string/heightLabel"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:popupBackground="@drawable/graybackground2"

                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:paddingTop="0dp"
                android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_span="0"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Activity Level"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/activity_level"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Goal"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/activity_level"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/goal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        android:radius="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
        android:onClick="saveAction"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />


</LinearLayout>
```

`

Fragmenthome.java

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;



   public class FragmentHome extends   Fragment  implements  
   View.OnClickListener {


  private TextView caloriesTotal;

  private TextView caloriesRemain;

  private ListView listView;
  private LinearLayout mLayout;

   private Animation anim;

   ImageButton AddEntrybtn;
   ImageButton ResetEntry;
   Context context;

  int goalCalories;
   int totalCalorie;



    Button mButton;

    //Database
    private DatabaseHandler dba;

   private ArrayList<Food> dbFoods = new ArrayList<>();
   private CustomListViewAdapter foodAdapter;
   private Food myFood ;



    //fragment
   private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
   private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

   public FragmentHome() {
      // Required empty public constructor
   }




   @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, 
   false);



    caloriesTotal = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.tv_calorie_amount);

    caloriesRemain = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.calorieRemain);

    listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ListId);




    SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), 
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);

    goalCalories = 
     Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", 
    "2000"));



    AddEntrybtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.AddItems);




    AddEntrybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(4);


        }
    });



    ResetEntry = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.ResetEntry);
    ResetEntry.setOnClickListener(this);







    refreshData();



    anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    listView.startAnimation(anim);

    return myView;


  }




    public void reset ()  {

  //


    dbFoods.clear();

    dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();


    //Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){

        String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
        String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
        int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
        int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

        Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

        myFood= new Food();
        myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
        myFood.setFoodName(name);
        myFood.setCalories(cal);
        myFood.setRecordDate(date);

        dbFoods.clear();

        dbFoods.remove(myFood);
        foodsFromDB.remove(myFood);
       dba.deleteFood(foodId);
    }
    dba.close();

    //setting food Adapter:
    foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
    R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
    listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
    foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    listView.startAnimation(anim);


    }



   public void refreshData (){




    dbFoods.clear();

    dba = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    ArrayList<Food> foodsFromDB = dba.getFoods();

    totalCalorie = dba.totalCalories();




    String formattedCalories = Utils.formatNumber(totalCalorie);
    String formattedRemain = Utils.formatNumber(goalCalories - 
    totalCalorie);


    //setting the editTexts:


    caloriesTotal.setText("Total Calories: " + formattedCalories);

   caloriesRemain.setText(formattedRemain);




    SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), 
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);




    goalCalories = 
    Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", 
     "2000"));




    //Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < foodsFromDB.size(); i ++){

        String name = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodName();
        String date = foodsFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
        int cal = foodsFromDB.get(i).getCalories();
        int foodId = foodsFromDB.get(i).getFoodId();

        Log.v("Food Id", String.valueOf(foodId));

        myFood= new Food();
        myFood.setFoodId(foodId);
        myFood.setFoodName(name);
        myFood.setCalories(cal);
        myFood.setRecordDate(date);

        dbFoods.add(myFood);
    }
    dba.close();

    //setting food Adapter:
    foodAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(), 
   R.layout.row_item,dbFoods);
    listView.setAdapter(foodAdapter);
    foodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fading);
    listView.startAnimation(anim);

 }


    //save prefs
    public void savePrefs(String key, int value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.apply();
   }
    //get prefs
   public int loadPrefs(String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, value);
   }




 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();



    String username1 = username.getString("Username");

    TextView userMain= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.User);

    userMain.setText(username1);




   }


  @Override
    public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();



}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

    @Override
   public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    startActivity( new Intent(getContext(),MainActivity.class));
   }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.AddItems:

            AddEntry addEntry    = new AddEntry();

            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FragmentHolder,addEntry)

                    .commit();


            break;

        case R.id.action_settings:

            Intent preferenceScreenIntent = new Intent(getContext(), 
             PreferenceScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(preferenceScreenIntent);



            break;


        case R.id.ResetEntry:


           reset();
            anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), 
            R.anim.fading);
            listView.startAnimation(anim);
            break;


      }


    }
 }
```

preference.xml

```
    <PreferenceScreen     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <PreferenceCategory android:title="User Settings">
   <EditTextPreference
     android:title="Daily Calorie Amount"
    android:inputType="number"
   android:defaultValue="2000"
   android:key="@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount"
  android:summary="@string/prefs_description_daily_calorie_amount" />




  </PreferenceCategory>



  </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so you have lines

```
SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
editor.putInt("tdee", tdee);
editor.commit();
```

which are storing your value in `SharedPreferences`. where do you have fetching this value? (smth like below)

```
int tdee = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0).getInt("tdee");
```

why do you say that `int` isn't stored? in my opinion is stored perfectly and you are not trying to restore it in e.g. `onCreate` at all (basing on posted code)

also: try to clear your code before posting question/answer, strip code from unnecesary and not related to problem lines

Comment: For some reason when I click the save button on the profile.java it does not display on fragment home. Thats where I'm trying to fetch the value "SharedPreferences".

 I had added this line of code for fragment home

  SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), 
    R.xml.activity_preference, false);

    goalCalories = 
     Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount", 
    "2000"));
thinking it would fetch value from profile.java

Comment: you are saving your int using "tdee" key and `putInt` method (this part in my ans), but you are trying to read using "prefs_key_daily_calorie_am‌​ount" key and `getString` method... two completely different values. also "prefs_key_daily_calorie_am‌​ount" is not the same key as declared in xml "@string/prefs_key_daily_calorie_amount". you messed up everything: default preferences, custom preferences, keys, type of fields... you HAVE to read more about `SharedPreferences` in Android and additionaly smth about references to resources...